# Ember development server appears to be running in test mode

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

When I run `ember serve` while logging out the `environment` variable in `config/environment.js`, I see three values logged:

1. `undefined`
2. `development`
3. `test`

(This is in an inherited project.)

In a fresh app created using `ember new my-app`, I see three values also:

1. `development`
2. `test`
3. `development`

Which leads me to believe my inherited project is running in `test` mode and a fresh project is running in `development` mode as I would expect.

Running `ember serve --environment=development` does not change the observed behavior in the inherited project.

My questions are why do I see three values logged when running `ember serve` and how can I figure out why my development environment is running in `test`?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever calls `project.config(environment)` is what dictates the `environment` argument in the config function. If anything calls this function without an argument then you'll see `undefined`.

As for determining *why* it's running in test mode, I'd try throwing a debugger statement in your editor (if possible) then see what's calling it with `"test"`. If that's not possible then try printing a call stack somewhere in the function:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  ...
  console.log('current environment: ', environment);
  console.log(new Error().stack);
}
```

You'll see something like:

```
CURRENT ENVIRONMENT:  development
Error
    at module.exports (.../config/environment.js:73:15)
    at Project.configWithoutCache (.../node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:273:47)
    at Project.config (.../node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:257:21)
    at Watcher.module.exports [as serveURL] (.../node_modules/ember-cli/lib/utilities/get-serve-url.js:6:24)
    at Watcher.didChange (.../node_modules/ember-cli/lib/models/watcher.js:51:40)
    at Watcher.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at Watcher.triggerChange (.../node_modules/ember-cli-broccoli-sane-watcher/index.js:174:8)
    at tryCatcher (.../node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:323:19)
    at invokeCallback (.../node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:495:31)
    at publish (.../node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:481:7)
    at flush (.../node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2402:5)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

where you can work your way back to see what's setting the environment (in this case it's `ember-cli`).